# Make an Image have rounded corners with Objective-C / pure C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How do you make an NSImage Image have rounded corners? I'm doing Mac Dev not iPhone dev.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, not iPhone...but, have a look here http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/ You might find some clues to do it in a similar way for NSImage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean you want to *draw* a square image cropped to a rounded rectangle, take a look at NSBezierPath's clipping functions. Just clip to the frame you want and draw.

Answer (score 0):

Make the corners of a regular rectangular NSImage transparent.  You can do that by ANDing the alpha channel of the bitmap or image with an appropriate round-rect mask or mask image.